# Where and how ASP.NET MVC 5 implement jQuery/AJAX validation during registration and Login

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using the built-in MVC 5 template in Visual Studio 2013.
As far as I saw, this MVC 5 framework seems that it's already implemented the jQuery/AJAX validation during registration and Login, because when I tried to input some invalid data into account and/or password fields, the error messages appear immediately without refreshing the page.

So can anyone please explain how does MVC 5 framework achieve this effect?
I guess by using the CSS classes?

Comment: you'll want to look into "unobtrusive javascript" in mvc. essentially, it's using data elements inside the tags to trigger javascript validation on those fields.

Comment: hi @pennstatephil good to know. Could you please elaborate your comment in an answer? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of MVC3, they are using [jquery's unobtrusive validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/), as described in a [blog post by Brad Wilson](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html). This post walks through how unobtrusive validation works, and how MS applies the attributes to your fields.